# Sum of a Linked list

Tags: c

Im currently facing a problem with my code when trying a sum of a linked list, Im trying to call the linked list from my code and am having trouble compiling. Im not sure what to do in this situation.

```
PE12.c: In function ‘sumOfLinkedList’:
PE12.c:69:28: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘Link’ and ‘struct Link’)
        sum = *current_link + *current_link->next;
                            ^
```

This is what I currently am getting for compiling errors.

And here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc, free, NULL */
#include "link.h"

#define ARR_SZ 6

/* function for step 1 */
Link* getNewLink(int value, Link* next); 

/* function for step 4 */
void printLinkedList(Link* head); 

/* function for step 5 */
int sumOfLinkedList(Link* head);  

int main() {
    Link* head = NULL;
    int array[ARR_SZ] = {7, 1, -4, 16, 0, 3};
    int arrLen = ARR_SZ;
    int i = 0;


    /* Step 1: add the value -2 to the linked list */
    getNewLink(-2, head);
    /* TODO - Your code for Step 1 goes here 
     * You must also implement getNewLink() */
     
    /* Step 2: print the value at head */
    printf("%p", head);
    /* TODO - Your code for Step 2 goes here  */
    /* Step 3: add the 6 values from array to the linked list */
    for(i=0; i <= array[i] && i < arrLen; ++i) {
        getNewLink(i, head);
    } 
    /* TODO - Your code for Step 3 goes here */
    /* Step 4 */
    printLinkedList(head);

    /* Step 5 */
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sumOfLinkedList(head));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Link* getNewLink(int value, Link* next) {

    Link* newNode = (Link*) malloc(sizeof(Link));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    return newNode;
}

void printLinkedList(Link* head) {
    
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int sumOfLinkedList(Link* head) {

    int sum;
    
    Link *current_link = head;
       while ( current_link != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current_link->value);
       sum = *current_link + *current_link->next;
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what im doing wrong here?

Comment: You should be adding the values in the list nodes, not the structures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `current_link->value` to the `sum`. Dereferencing the pointers returns the `Link` structures, which can't be added.

You have to iterate through the list, by following the `next` pointers.

You also have to initialize `sum` to `0`.

There's no need for separate `head` and `current_link` variables. You can use the same variable in the loop as the function parameter.

```
int sumOfLinkedList(Link* current_link) {

    int sum = 0;
    
    while ( current_link != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current_link->value);
        sum += current_link->value;
        current_link = current_link->next;
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hey Im now getting a weird error with my previous statement 
```printf("%p\n", head);```
Its returning Nill in console

Comment: That means `head` is a null pointer.

Comment: You initialize `Link* head = NULL;` and never reassign it. So it's still `NULL`.

Comment: Change `getNewLink(-2, head);` to `head = getNewLink(-2, head);` And make the same change in the `for` loop.

Comment: Why do you have this condition in the loop? `i <= array[i]`. That will stop when it gets to `-4` because `2 <= -4` is false.